# certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted error when calling SQL Server from a blazor wasm application

Tags: sql-server, blazor, ssl-certificate, progressive-web-apps

I have a blazor pwa application that I have deployed to a local iis server.  I get a certificate chain not trusted error when calling down to a remote sql server via entity framework.

connection string snippet: Trusted_Connection=True;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090325): The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

On non pwa applications, I have worked around this issue by telling the sql connection to TrustServerCertificate.  This doesn't seem to work for the blazor pwa.  The database is not encrypted and I have indicated that in the conneciton string as well.  I upgraded from .net 6 to .net 7 but that did not fix the problem.   I have swapped Encrypt=False in and out of the connection string.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `Trusted_Connection` or use `Integrated Security`, not both. Ref: [SqlConnection.ConnectionString Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring).

Comment: Did you apply a valid certificate to SQL Server to use for encryption? If you didn't, you should be using `Encrypt=false;`. This setting is on by default with newer versions of the SQL Server driver.

Comment: Ideally set up a proper SSL certificate for SQL Server, especially if you are using SQL Server over the internet. This should have the full domain name of the server (ie the one you use to connect to it) as the Subject Alt Name. The machine you are connecting from also needs to trust the issuer of this certificate